# How can I get a blurred stroke in java.awt.geom

Tags: java, rectangles, stroke

I would like to be able to control the blurred/fuzzy level of the stroke of a rectangle. It should be realized within the `java.awt.geom` package. I know how to change the shape of the stroke, like on [this jhlabs page](http://www.jhlabs.com/java/java2d/strokes/), but I don't know how to *blur* the stroke.

[image: blurred stroke]

This is basically what I want for my final result.

Comment: If you want to stay in `java.awt.geom` package, is using a `Line2D` object okay?

Comment: If I get the same result sure. I will also try it. maybe I will get it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/org/geotools/styling/StrokeImpl.java.html) is an open-source class that allows the styling of strokes. It does a good job of explaining itself within its commented code.

From looking at this class, to achieve a *blurred* stroke look. You will have to mess with the opacity and width of the stroke. Perhaps at the end of the stroke.

Hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

Comment: It's an org.geotools.styling.Stroke not a Stroke from java.awt.geom

Comment: Yea, I couldn't find any in `java.awt.geom`, I figured I'd throw this up here just in case you needed some direction. :P Sorry! @freehell